# Invoking Spring MVC controller method from another thread (javax.jms.MessageListener)

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm looking for a way of sending messages to my Spring MVC Controller from another thread. In particular my thread is an implementation of `javax.jms.MessageListener` which listens for messages on a ActiveMQ queue. As soon as I get a new message in the Queue, the jms MessageListener's `onMessage()` method is invoked. However, now I want to invoke another method in my spring controller whenever MessageListener's `onMessage()` is invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controllers in Spring MVC are not intended to be directly invoked the way you are looking for, but are designed to handle and respond to to web requests. A cleaner way to handle what you are doing will be to move the controller logic that you plan to invoke to a services layer and invoke this common services layer from controller and JMS listener.

If you absolutely want to, you can always autowire in a controller and invoke methods on it as if it is a normal POJO though.

Comment: But what about Spring 3.2 support of DeferredResult? If you dont inject the controller on the MessageListener how are you supposed to get the DefferredResult? Delegating the DefferredResult handling to a service seems counterintuitive to me